# Java how to check if it's Vista, Windows 7 or higher with apache commons

Tags: java, windows

I understand that you can do

```
SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_VISTA || SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_7
```

but is there a way to do this programatically for all future versions windows, so that the method is something like:

```
isWindowsVistaOrHigher()
```

Comment: Why should Java care, as long as there's a suitable JVM?

Comment: There are some vista/windows 7 OS features that I want to leverage when possible that aren't available in older versions of Windows. So I need to do only call this code if it's Vista, Windows 7, or higher.

Comment: *"some .. features"* Like what, specifically?  Why won't try/catch be enough to wort the difference?

Comment: @Jeffrey: Not exactly. Not just Vista || Windows 7 but Vista || orhigher

Comment: @AndrewThompson Try catch is not enough.

Comment: A little louder this time ***Like what, specifically?***  Or is guessing part of the 'fun' of helping you?

Comment: @AndrewThompson To be honest, the why isn't important as much as the how. I'd tell you more about the why but it's actually quite complex and long, and has to do with a lot of historical code that can't be changed. I don't prefer going this route, but I don't really have a choice

Comment: @StephaneGrenier In your example, I don't think this will *ever* return `true`: `SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_VISTA && SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_7`

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes sorry, that's right

Comment: I don't know if you can check this like you want but wouldn't it be an alternative to check if it's **not** a version < Win Vista, e.g. if(!isWin95 && !isWin98 && !isWinMe && ...){// your code}

Comment: @SimonSez That's what I'm doing right now. I'm just not a fan of that solution because I don't if it's sustainable. But that's my current solution ;)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be sustainable? It would only not be sustainable if a newer version of Windows magically returned true for one of those values. I don't see why that would happen.

Comment: I guess that's the answer then. Just check that it's not one of the early systems, one by one. Whoever wants to be the first to answer that I'll mark as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was:

```
public boolean isVistaOrHigher()
{
   return !SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_XP && !SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_98 && ... ;
}
```

Comment: This assumes you are running on Windows.  Look at the source for SystemUtils, it is just doing a simple check on os.version and os.name.  This might be what you want `SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS && Double.parseDouble(SystemUtils.OS_VERSION) >= 6.0`.  I would at least add SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS to your check.

Comment: @Patrick I actually do a IS_OS_WINDOWS first because we also support the Mac OS, I just didn't add it because not everyone needs it and I felt it just added more noise to the answer ;) Good catch though :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need Apache Commons at all. The system property `os.version` contains the internal OS version (`os.name` is the human-readable name and will contain `Windows` followed by more specific info such as `Vista`). I think on Windows 7 if you call `System.getProperty("os.version")` you will get `6.1` while Vista is `6.0`. Assuming they don't change the convention, you could try to take the part up to the first dot if a dot is present (using `String.substring()` and `String.indexOf('.')`), parse the substring as an integer using `Integer.parseInt()` and compare if the resulting value is at least `6`.